# Radiobutton unchecked after removing clone from the DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am performing an Ajax call in a bootstrap modal and replacing the contents (.modal-contents) with a partial view on success.  I subsequently center the modal using the centerModals function below.  I have a radiobutton in the partial view that is checked by default.  When I initially load the partial view in the Ajax "done" method, it is checked.  After calling the centerModals function, specifically the $clone.remove() function, the radiobutton is unchecked or if I remove the call to the centerModals function the radiobutton remains checked.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
        //Ajax call from modal
    $.ajax({
        url: viewCustomer.loadNewDiscountUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ customerID: customerID }),
        cache: false,
        timeout: 20000
    }).done(function (result) {    
        //Load partial view. The radiobutton in result is checked
        $('#TransctionModalContent').html(result);            
        global.centerModals();            
    });


    //Script to center modal in global object
    centerModals: function ($element) {
    var $modals;
    if ($element != null && $element.length) {
        $modals = $element;
    } else {
        $modals = $('.modal');
    }
    $modals.each(function (i) {
        var $clone = $(this).clone().css('display', 'block').appendTo('body');
        var top = Math.round(($clone.height() - $clone.find('.modal-content').height()) / 2);
        top = top > 0 ? top : 0;
        $clone.remove();
        $(this).find('.modal-content').css("margin-top", top);
    });
    }
```

Comment: A radio button group can only have one button marked as selected. When you add the clone to the DOM, it removes the `'selected` attribute from the original (because the clone has a one that is selected)

Comment: That makes perfect sense!   Thanks for the swift response.  I am now retrieving all the selected radiobuttons before the clone operation and restoring their state after the clone is removed.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do something with the fact that `$(this).clone()` copies the radio button which has the same name of the original one. Hence now you have 2 - one checked and another one unchecked. My best guess is `$clone.remove();` removes the checked one somehow... but without debugging I cannot be so sure.